# Creating a lookup table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

**Edited for clarification:**

I'm trying to create a lookup table in Django and not quite sure how to implement. I have two tables, one with "money spent" and the second with "free gifts". You spend a certain amount, the more free gifts you get (one to many).

For example in image below, if you spend **$50**, you get **Ice Cream** and **Soda** as free gifts. At a lower level you would only get one free gift.

[image]

I created this model but running migrations doesn't like it.

```
class GiftDefaults(models.Model):
    """
    Default gifts associated with spending levels
    """

    # Fields
    gift = models.ForeignKey(Gift, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    spending_level = models.ForeignKey(SpendingLevel, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gift
```

What is the proper way to create this lookup table in Django models? Not sure what's wrong with my Model.

Here was the output from makemigrations, as you can see it skipped "Gifts" column.

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='GiftDefaults',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('spending_level', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='giving.SpendingLevel')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Comment: What errors does the migrations produces?

Comment: Furthermoer the diagram actually indicates that the relations should work in the opposite direction.

Comment: No error was thrown, but the migrations didn't create the table as I would have expected, and in the CMS there is no multiple foreignkeys. It only created the "gift" column and ignored the other. Regarding the diagram, I don't have a modeling tool so just used LucidChart to fake it

Comment: Did you add the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, it's in the INSTALLED_APPS. I've actually gotten other models to work, it's just that it skipped a column during makemigrations and not sure why

Comment: There is something wrong with Gift model, did you import that correctly? Is that also in the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Found the issue. If you look at my code above, there is a comma after the "gift" line. That broke it as I suspect it thought it was a tupel. Removed it and migrations worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the comma at the end of the `gift` column creation, that made the code break it out into a tuple I suspect. The correct code should have been

```
class GiftDefaults(models.Model):
    """
    Default gifts associated with spending levels
    """

    # Fields
    gift = models.ForeignKey(Gift, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    spending_level = models.ForeignKey(SpendingLevel, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gift
```

Once this was removed, the `Makemigrations` worked as expected.